# Have n child div's have equal width based on parent's width

Tags: html, css

I've seen several questions about this but I don't see a concise answer.  I want to know if it's possible to have n elements under a parent element, where all these elements are equal in width regardless of the text size.  For example, if parent element is 1000px, I'd like the child elements to automatically take the width of 1000/n. Is this possible with CSS?

Comment: Using `flex` concept or `display: table-cell`

Comment: This question is vague. Are you talking about horizontal columns, or vertical rows? Where is your code? With 3,899 rep, I would have expected you would have known to show us your code here on SO. All children would need a width of 100% to have the same width of the parent. We have no idea what your talking about, without code, without examples..

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with fixed table layout.

```css
.table {
    display: table;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
.table > div {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
    <div>cell</div>
    <div>cell - there is more content inside it</div>
    <div>cell</div>
    <div>cell</div>
    <div>cell</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the content of each child have the same width, this can be done in an elegant way with flexbox. Check this minimal example:

**HTML (insert or remove children to see):**

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">child</div>
    <div class="child">child</div>
    <div class="child">child</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.parent {
    display: box;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    -webkit-box-align: start;
    -moz-box-align: start;
    box-align: start;
    width: 100%;
}

.child {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    box-flex: 1;
    border: 1px solid green;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**FIDDLE:** https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/fPfvN/165/

Answer (score -1):

You can use width in percentage for the child div. Also, you need to make child position:absolute and parent position:relative.

Comment: You'd have to hard code the percentage.  I'd like mine to be dynamic.

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to do that with only CSS. Use javascript to do that dinamically.

Comment: @ciuschi You're wrong.